# Mount an external folder as a resource in Wicket

Tags: java, wicket

What I am trying to accomplish is for some image references in a css file to be located in a folder seperate to the actual application.

Is it possible to mount an external folder as a resource in Wicket?

In pseudocode this is what I am trying to do:

```
public class Application extends WicketApplication
{
    init()
    {
        mountResource(new FolderResource("Path/to/some/folder", "someid"));
    }
}
```

So that the .css class would reference the resources like this:

```
.someclass
{
    url("resources/someid/images/image.png")
}
```

I'm sure I've seen this somewhere but I just can't seem to be able to find it again...

**EDIT**
Should also note that im currently running on Wicket 1.4

Comment: I think this StackOverflow question list all the possibilities that you have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279232/images-referencing-in-css-with-wicket-for-hundreds-of-images. Personally I prefer and would try to implement the answer of martin-g.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As simple as following.

**MyApplication.java:**

```
public class MyApplication extends WebApplication {
    ...
    public void init() {
        ...
        final String resourceId = "images";
        getSharedResources().add(resourceId, new FolderResource(new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("img"))));    
        mountSharedResource("/image", Application.class.getName() + "/" + resourceId);
    }        
    ...
}
```

**FolderResource.java:**

```
public class FolderResource extends WebResource {

    private File folder;

    public FolderResource(File folder) {
        this.folder = folder;
    }

    @Override
    public IResourceStream getResourceStream() {
        String fileName = getParameters().getString("file");
        File file = new File(folder, fileName);
        return new FileResourceStream(file);
    }
}
```

And then you can get any image from "img" folder inside your application by simple URL:

```
/your-application/app/image?file=any-image.png
```

Here "/your-application" is the application context path, "/app" is the Wicket servlet mapping in web.xml, and "any-image.png" is the name of the image file.

Comment: Slooow response:P TRook a time out on the project, this did help alot rhough!

Comment: How to to this in the current version of wicket?