# BufferedDynamicImageResource cached by browser

Tags: caching, wicket, browser-cache, dynamic-image-generation

To display a dynamically loaded image in my webapp I'm using a [`BufferedDynamicImageResource`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/index.html?org/apache/wicket/markup/html/image/resource/BufferedDynamicImageResource.html). (It just loads the image from a backend server based on an database id.)

The URL of the image resource ends up as:

```
http://localhost:8080/wicket/page?17-IResourceListener-logotype
                                  ^^
                            sequence number
```

where the sequence number increases for each such image I generate.

**The problem** is that the URL is reused from execution to execution (the sequence number is reset to 0) so when I restart the server the browser does not fetch the newly generated images, but instead uses the cached versions (which were generated last execution of the webapp).

**My Question:** What is the best way to avoid this behavior? (If I could for instance add the database id of the image which is loaded to the URL, everything would work fine.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common way to solve this would be to mount the resource as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675750/mount-an-external-folder-as-a-resource-in-wicket). Using this approach, you could use the id as a parameter or add an (ignored) random parameter to prevent caching completely.

Comment: Thank you. Works great. I also found [this resource](http://web.archive.org/web/20120702095421/http://wicketinaction.com/2011/07/wicket-1-5-mounting-resources/comment-page-1/) which describes the same approach.

Comment: This book is a pretty good resource for about everything wicket (not affieliated with the author in any way)